# Is it incorrect to use "&" instead of "and" in a professional document?

Tags: conjunctions

To save space, I often use "&" instead of "and". I noticed many B2B websites,brochures and reports don't use "&". Is it wrong, or considered shabby if you use the short form?

Comment: It's considered "most informal": http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/ampersand